# How to suppress specific warnings in g++

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I want to suppress specific warnings from g++. I'm aware of the `-Wno-XXX` flag, but I'm looking for something more specific. I want **some** of the warnings in `-Weffc++`, but not **all** of them. Something like what you can do with lint - disable specific messages.

Is there a built in way in gcc to do this? Do I have to write a wrapper script?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378560/how-to-disable-gcc-warnings-for-a-few-lines-of-code/26003732#26003732) if you want to disable the warnings for `n` lines of code.

Comment: In case you are wiliiing to add it to the source code file(s) you can do the following as described here (and probably in other answers as well): https://codeyarns.com/2014/03/11/how-to-selectively-ignore-a-gcc-warning/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

<s>Unfortunately, this feature isn't provided by g++.</s> In VC++, you could use [#pragma warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e(VS.80).aspx) to disable some specific warnings. In gcc, the closest you can have is [diagnostic pragmas](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html), which let you enable/disable certain types of diagnostics for certain files or projects.

*Edit*: GCC supports pushing/popping warnings since 4.6.4 (see [changelog](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/changes.html))

Comment: This is not correct, you can use the diagnostic pragma just around one line of code by pushing/popping the state and then tweaking the diagnostic within that push/pop area.

Comment: @AlexisWilke Indeed, this was added in gcc a few years after my answer, let me update it!

Answer (score 13):

For some warnings, there is a command line switch to disable them. In order to know which switch to use, pass `-fdiagnostics-show-option` to gcc.

Comment: The command line option to get the name of the warning is useful.

Answer (score 3):

You could just use ***grep -v*** on the output.

Depending on the warning you wish to disable, you can sometimes correct in code.  E.g.:

```
int main()
{
  int i;
}
```

*Generates:*  foo.cc:4: warning: unused variable 'i'

Whereas this does not:

```
#define MARKUSED(X)  ((void)(&(X)))

int main()
{
  int i;
  MARKUSED(i);
}
```

Comment: GCC also has the keyword __extension__ wish will suppress warnings from the next statement.

Comment: @GiladNaor Surround a section of code, e.g. `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wfloat-equal"` and `#pragma GCC diagnostic pop`

Comment: The op is asking for generic solution, not limited to this unused variable  warning.

Answer (score 1):

pipe standard error to a filter that removes things you don't want to see. For example, this is my make file:

```
main.o:  main.cpp
    g++ -c -Wall main.cpp 2>&1 | grep -v Wunused-variable
```

Comment: It seems to be more complex as a warning may fit multiple lines (say, when it contains code snippets).

Comment: Also if you use `-Werror`, hiding the warning is not that useful (to not say, it's not going to help you one bit).

Answer (score 0):

When my colleagues are trying to prevent me from writing concise code, they use g++ command-line option

```
-Werror-parenthesis
```

And I disable this error in my code:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wparentheses"
```