# How to suppress warning in some .cpp files in Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, build, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

How to  suppress warning in some .cpp files in Eclipse?

For example during build procees I want to get warning from file A.cpp. but don't want from B.cpp.

If it matters I'm using Eclipse Kepler.

Comment: There's a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321839/how-to-disable-warnings-for-particular-include-files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable warnings for particular include files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321839/how-to-disable-warnings-for-particular-include-files)