# How to supress warnings for the includes?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a project which uses `tinyxml2` library. I have a very long list of compiler options where the `-Werror=zero-as-null-pointer-constant` is listed among others. So, everywhere I include the `tinyxml2.h` I have the errors: `0 used as null pointer`, however my code does not have such problems. Is there a way to disable some compiler options for the includes because I can't control them?

P.S. If it is impossible to do via `gcc/clang` options, perhaps it is possible to do via cmake? Or I would like to know both ways if they are exist.

Comment: Both GCC and Clang have *pragmas* to (possibly temporarily) disable warnings. [The GCC online documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) might be a good place to start looking.

Comment: ... And if you don't want to litter all of *your* code with pragmas, create a header that simply includes `tinyxml2.h` and include *that* in your source. Then you can add support for more compilers if needed, all at a single place.

Answer (score 2):

You could use suppression pragmas.

This is supported for GCC and VC++ compilers, and it looks like this:

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable : 4244)
#pragma warning(disable : 4127)
#pragma warning(disable : 4512)
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#pragma warning(pop)
```

Here are the detailed specs:

- [VC++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e.aspx)
- [GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378560/how-to-disable-gcc-warnings-for-a-few-lines-of-code)

Answer (score 1):

You can mark the include directory for `tinyxml2` as a system include directory, which will suppress the warnings coming from there.

With GCC/Clang, you can do this with `-isystem` instead of `-I`, or with the keyword `SYSTEM` when you add include directories in CMake.

For instance

```
include_directories(SYSTEM ${SOME_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

or, better,

```
target_include_directories(myExe SYSTEM ${SOME_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

Comment: To be clear, warnings being suppressed is one of the effects of marking a directory as a system include directory, but not the only one.