# Getting around compound literals in C++ to removing the warning

Tags: c++

I'm working with libsystemd-dev (a C library) in my C++ application.

I get a gcc/clang pedantic warning

> compound literals are a C99-specific feature

with this code:

```
#include <systemd/sd-bus.h>

void foo()
{
  sd_bus_error err = SD_BUS_ERROR_NULL;  // compound literals are a C99-specific feature
  ...
}
```

Looking at the `<systemd/sd-bus.h>` header file, I see:

```
typedef struct {
        const char *name;
        const char *message;
        int _need_free;
} sd_bus_error;

#define SD_BUS_ERROR_MAKE_CONST(name, message) ((const sd_bus_error) {(name), (message), 0})
#define SD_BUS_ERROR_NULL SD_BUS_ERROR_MAKE_CONST(NULL, NULL)
```

This means I can solve the warning with:

```
#include <systemd/sd-bus.h>

void foo()
{
  sd_bus_error err = {nullptr, nullptr, 0};
  ...
}
```

But is that a good idea?  If the library changes, my code would need to change too so I feel that it's volatile.  Is there really any problem with this warning? Is there a better way to get around it?

There is always the method of just using compiler flags to disable the warning, but I was wondering if there could be an encouraged method in-code to address this.

Comment: Enabling the extension isn't the end of the world.

Comment: The purist that I am, I would have a 'thunk' file that wrapped up these C constructs in a gobal C++ function. I would only enable to extensions for that thunk file and call the C++ functions whenever I needed the behavior.

Comment: A C library may not be rewritten with C++ in mind. After all, it is perfectly valid C99. So you may well encounter some inelegance when you try to use it from C++. But either way ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable warnings for particular include files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321839/how-to-disable-warnings-for-particular-include-files)

Comment: Disabling specific warnings is obviously an easy solution.  I was wonder if there was something that I was missing that I could do in the code to address the issue directly.  It seems the answer is 'no'.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Omnifarious already hinted at one approach - use extensions inside a wrapper function. The slightly more robust method is to use an `extern "C"` wrapper function, in its own Translation Unit. Compile that whole Translation Unit as C11, *without* extensions.

This is generally more robust. Mixing code at source level requires advanced compiler support, whereas linking C and C++ is fairly straightforward.

Comment: Yeah, the `extern "C"` approach is more portable.