# How to set 2 byte wchar_t output?

Tags: gcc, ld, binutils, eabi

The GCC uses a 4-byte `wchar_t` by default. I can set the option `-fshort-wchar` to get 2 bytes per `wchar_t` in the `L"string constants"`. But when I set the compiler option to my source file I get the famous warning message

> foo.o uses 2-byte `wchar_t` yet the output is to use 4-byte `wchar_t`; use of `wchar_t` values across objects may fail

Since I really want 2-byte `wchar_t` I also want the output to use this variant. Is there any linker option to tell it what I want?

**Edit**

This warning doesn't inhibit the linker to produce a valid output. But the dozens of false warnings cover other messages.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In binutils you can find this error message in `bfd/elf32-arm.c` as:

> "warning: %B uses %u-byte wchar_t yet the output is to use %u-byte
>   wchar_t; use of wchar_t values across objects may fail"

However, if you look further at binutils, you'd realize that the output's wchar_t size is not initialized to 4 anywhere. So what determines the "output wchar_t size"? Actually, the first object given to `ld` initializes the output attributes. The next objects merge their attributes into it. If you link with gcc/g++, it executes `ld` internally, so try `gcc -v` and see how `ld` is executed. This will give you insight into what internal object files (in addition to your own) it implicitly links into your executable.

For example, linking with gcc (e.g. `gcc -v -shared -o libfoobar.so foo.o bar.o`) results in invocation of:

`ld ... crtbegin_so.o foo.o bar.o crtend_so.o ...`

i.e. the following objects are actually linked (in order):

- crtbegin_so.o (implicitly)
- foo.o
- bar.o
- crtend_so.o (implicitly)

Here's what ld does:

1. The output attributes set starts off empty.
2. Merging **crtbegin_so.o** attributes. Now output attributes contain `out_attr[Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t] == 4`
3. Merging **foo.o** attributes. If foo.o was built with `-fshort-wchar`, then `in_attr[Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t] == 2` and this will result in a conflict and the warning you're seeing.

If you were to swap crtbegin_so.o and foo.o on the ld command line, you'd get the following warning instead:

> ld: warning:
>   android-ndk-r9d/platforms/android-16/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o
>   uses 4-byte wchar_t yet the output is to use 2-byte wchar_t; use of
>   wchar_t values across objects may fail

As you can see, it's not a matter of incompatibility of the input with the output, but rather (perceived) incompatibility between two object files linked together.

What can we do about it?

- [As of 2008](https://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2008-07/msg00125.html), `ld` supports the `--no-wchar-size-warning` flag to suppress this warning. But as you said, indiscriminately suppressing warnings has its drawbacks.
- You can rebuild your toolchain with -fshort-wchar.
- You can strip the `Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t` tags from your internal gcc object binaries if you truly believe they're `sizeof(wchar_t)`-agnostic. This might be easier than rebuilding your toolchain. For that, you can use [this utility](https://gist.github.com/ikonst/3427195) I once wrote. (You might need to unpack libgcc.a, change its object files and repack it.)

Comment: +1 for rebuilding the toolchain. I'd guess you'd need a libc(++) as well.

Comment: AFAIK libstdc++ is built (only) as part of the toolchain (g++).

Answer (score 1):

That's a **warning**, not error. You can ignore it but that will cause problems if you link against others libraries that were compiled with 4-byte `wchar_t`. If you must use 2-byte `wchar_t` then you'll have to find a replacement for those libraries or recompile them

You may also try `-fwide-exec-charset=UTF-16`

> - `-fwide-exec-charset=charset`
>
>   - Set the wide execution character set, used for wide string and character constants. The default is UTF-32 or UTF-16, whichever corresponds to the width of `wchar_t`. As with `-fexec-charset`, charset can be any encoding supported by the system's iconv library routine; however, you will have problems with encodings that do not fit exactly in `wchar_t`.

If you have C11 support you can just use [`char16_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/char16_t) (with the `u` prefix for string literals) and convert to `wchar_t` when necessary

Comment: I didn't write about an error message though. It's hard to ignore, when you get a dozen of such messages. Well I replaced the wchar_t function implementation. So none of "those libraries" are linked. So the question is still "How to the the output".

Comment: If you want to disable the warning just use [-w](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079997/disable-specific-warnings-in-gcc/1080013#1080013

Comment: Well I would like having the wchar_t message suppressed to see the other, probably more important warnings.

Comment: you can selectively disable a specific warning. Look at the latter link on my comment above

Comment: Your link points to "Many options have long names starting with ..." but there is also an answer with a link to http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.3/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas But this controls compiler diagnostics while the warning in question is issued by the linker.