# How can I be sure a library doesn't use wchar_t

Tags: gcc, ld, binutils, eabi

While I worked to link a library on a new platform, I got the following error:

> foo.o uses 2-byte `wchar_t` yet the output is to use 4-byte `wchar_t`; use of `wchar_t` values across objects may fail

I searched stackoverflow and found this thread: [How to set 2 byte wchar_t output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19489354/how-to-set-2-byte-wchar-t-output)

I saw the answer there and it is really helpful

> You can strip the `Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t` tags from your internal gcc object binaries if you truly believe they're `sizeof(wchar_t)`-agnostic.

Is there an automatic way I can be sure that the library is `sizeof(wchar_t)`-agnostic?

Thanks

Comment: Read the source code.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do you mean the source code of the library? This is an option for libraries without much dependencies, but I was aiming for a more automatic way. I'll edit the question.

Comment: instead of stripping the tag you should make sure that *your* code doesn't use any `wchar_t` and set `wchar_t` to what the library uses, unless you're making another library