# How to ignore warnings from 3rd party packages?

Tags: c++, boost, warnings

I'm using `boost` for a project I'm working on. Some of my files include one or more of the boost headers which in turn include other boost headers, which in one of them there is a variable which is set but not used. This prints an ugly warning to my screen which makes it hard to read the output especially when I have a real compilation error but I need to look carefully in the output to distinguish which text belongs to the set but not used warning and which is related to the real compilation error I want to solve.

I don't want to disable this warning to the entire project or even to some specific files in my project because I want to see this warning if I set a variable in my code but I don't use it. I want only the warning which happens in a specific line and specific file to be ignored.

Is there an option for `gcc` to suppress specific warnings in specific location in the code?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378560/how-to-disable-gcc-warnings-for-a-few-lines-of-code , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079997/disable-specific-warnings-in-gcc , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965093/selectively-disable-gcc-warnings-for-only-part-of-a-translation-unit

Comment: if you compile with gcc then use -isystem

Comment: @ezra That isn't quite what he's asking - he wants to be able to disable warnings for a specific file **and** at a specific inclusion point of his code. -isystem will disable warnings for a specific file, at all points of inclusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcc offers diagnostic pragmas. See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html.

Use these in your code before and after you `#include` those third party headers. Do not modify those the third party code to suit your compilation flags.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll give it a try and accept your answer if it works. It's a pity though I need to change the code, I was hoping to find an option to `gcc`, but I guess this option doesn't exist since it needs to many parameters.