# How do I turn off compiler warnings tagged with [enabled by default] in Code Blocks

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, codeblocks

I am trying to use constants in a class which should be okay in c++11 but I get this warning:

```
 warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
```

The problem is that I get this many (more than 10) times for every constant I declare. This effectively fills the build messages and makes any other compiler warnings impossible to find.
I would like to make it so this no longer shows up in my build messages box.

I know people like to see relevant code so here it is:

```
class GameState: public State
{
public:
    const Uint8 * keyStates;
    Point gameMousePos;
    int UIType;
    std::vector<UI *> UIs;
    Texture * lockingTex;
    HitBox * inGame;
    const int buttonDim = 100;
    const int buttonOffY = 70;//distance from bottom
    const int buttonOffX = 130;//distance from each other
    const int buttonTextOffY = 140;//text distance from bottom
    bool locking;
    bool noPlaceBool;
    float gameSpaceScale;
    HitBox * gameSpace;
    Texture * bkg;
    float windowRotSpeed;
    float inHandRotSpeed;
    float windowMoveSpeed;
    GameState();
    void handle_events();
    void logic();
    void render();
    void save();
    void load_save();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378560/how-to-disable-gcc-warnings-for-a-few-lines-of-code

Comment: Alternative duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079997/disable-specific-warnings-in-gcc

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but you *are* configured for C++11 compilation, right? And have you considered using  static `constexpr` for those ?

Comment: use `-std=c++11` to get rid of that warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that it should be static:

```
warning: non-static data member ...
```

So if you were to add the static keyword, it would solve your problem.

So change these:

```
const int buttonDim = 100;
```

With:

```
static const int buttonDim = 100;
```

And the warnings should go.

Note that was part of C++ for a very long time (only cl [Microsoft compiler] did not support it well before 2008 or so.)

---

As a side note, a good programmer wants to do the opposite: transform all warnings to errors to be forced to fix all warnings. I very rarely have to go around a warning and it is always rather edgy cases (like compare two floating point numbers with `==` or `!=`. So all of that to say, I would actually advice you use `-Werror` and always find the exact reason for a warning.

Of course, if you are working with someone else code... that's a different story. They may not want to fix their code.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler warning tells you exactly what to do:

> warning: non-static data member initializers only available with **-std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11** [enabled by default]

By default g++ uses C++03.
To activate C++11 features you need to tell the compiler to use C++11

```
g++ -std=c++11 stuff.cpp
```

Once you are using C++11 the default features ("enabled by default") for that language will be enabled.