# Disable warnings for specific included files

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-warnings, openni

I am using OpenNI on OS X, and for some reason its `.h` files are spitting out a lot of warnings all over the place, which is annoying.

Is there a way to turn off all warnings for the OpenNI include files?

Comment: This is a good reference: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html

Comment: @chris: if at all possible, it'd be great to find a solution that would not require me to modify the headers themselves, since I won't always have write access...

Comment: You could probably make use of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3394268/962089) around the include directives.

Comment: Write your own header that pushes the diagnostic state, sets it to whatever you want, includes the third party or system headers, then pops the diagnostic state back to what it was.

Comment: You could send the compiler output through a filter...

Comment: Don't you think you should find out where the warnings are coming from?

Comment: @stark: I know where they are coming from, as I said in the question, it's from OpenNI, a 3rd party library.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: that is still a bit invasive, as it requires me to modify code. I originally wanted to do it using command line switches only, and now I found a solution, `-isystem`, posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I can specify the include directories for `OpenNI` using the `-isystem` switch instead of `-I`.

`-isystem` makes gcc treat the include directories as system directories, and as such it won't generate any warnings for them.