# GCC does not honor 'pragma GCC diagnostic' to silence warnings

Tags: c++, gcc, openmp, compiler-warnings, pragma

We recently enabled `-Wall` for a project. Its enabled when GCC is at 4.7 or above (or Clang) because we can use [`GCC diagnostic`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html) to manage the output from the elevated warnings. We want to manage them from the source code, and ***not*** via command line arguments. (We don't want to pollute the command line, or ask library users to rediscover what is needed).

Under GCC 4.8 and 5.1, we are catching warnings that were disabled in a GCC diagnostic block for `-Wunused-variable`, `-Wunused-value`, `-Wunused-function` and `-Wunknown-pragmas`. Both GCCs accept `-fopenmp`, and both define `_OPENMP` in response to it, so I'm fairly certain it we should never see a `-Wunknown-pragmas` in response to `#prgam omp ...` (it *is* disabled, but it *is not* unknown).

```
g++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 -Wall -march=native -pipe -c nbtheory.cpp
nbtheory.cpp:655:0: warning: ignoring #pragma omp parallel [-Wunknown-pragmas]
  #pragma omp parallel
 ^
nbtheory.cpp:656:0: warning: ignoring #pragma omp sections [-Wunknown-pragmas]
   #pragma omp sections
 ^
...
```

In this particular case, the [file `nbtheroy.cpp`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/nbtheory.cpp) has the following guard in place to help manage that warning (only relevant parts are shown, but you can see everything from [the GitHub link](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/nbtheory.cpp)):

```c++
// Defines GCC_DIAGNOSTIC_AWARE if GCC 4.7 or above.
#include <misc.h>
...

#if GCC_DIAGNOSTIC_AWARE
# pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunknown-pragmas"
#endif

...
Integer ModularRoot(const Integer &a, const Integer &dp, const Integer &dq,
                    const Integer &p, const Integer &q, const Integer &u)
{
    Integer p2, q2;
    #pragma omp parallel
        #pragma omp sections
        {
            #pragma omp section
                p2 = ModularExponentiation((a % p), dp, p);
            #pragma omp section
                q2 = ModularExponentiation((a % q), dq, q);
        }
    return CRT(p2, p, q2, q, u);
}
...
```

Because the file is `*.cpp` (its effectively *the* translation unit), we ***do not*** perform a `#pragma GCC diagnostic push` at the beginning and `#pragma GCC diagnostic pop` at the end. (We do that for header files that are included, however). (We also tried doing it, but it did not help).

And here is `GCC_DIAGNOSTIC_AWARE` (from [`misc.h`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/misc.h)):

```c++
// Used to suppress some warnings in some header and implementation files.
//   Some platforms, like CentOS and OpenBSD, use old compilers that don't understand -Wno-unknown-pragma.
#define GCC_DIAGNOSTIC_AWARE ((__GNUC__ > 4 || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ >= 7)) || defined(__clang__))
```

I know the guard is working because adding a `#error` in the block causes an error. Also, commenting out the guard and calling out `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunknown-pragmas"` does not help. Finally, it works fine under Clang.

I'm also experiencing it for other warnings, like `-Wunused-variable`, `-Wunused-value` and `-Wunused-function`. I ***really*** don't want to pollute the command line as suggested with the potential duplicate.

How do I get the `GCC pragma diagnostic` mechanism to work as expected to silence warnings under GCC when using `-Wall`?

---

Related, if you want to reproduce it (its GNUmakefile based, and does not require configurations or autotools):

```
git clone https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp.git cryptopp-warn
cd cryptopp-warn
make
```

**EDIT**: we checked-in a patch that disables `-Wall` except for Clang. If you want to reproduce the old behavior, then:

```
git clone https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp.git cryptopp-warn
cd cryptopp-warn
export CXXFLAGS="-g2 -O3 -DNDEBUG -Wall"
make
```

Comment: I'd suggest first removing the `#if/#endif` (leaving just the `#pragma GCC ...`) to see if it's a problem with `GCC_DIAGNOSTIC_AWARE`.

Comment: @paxdiablo  - No joy. I disabled the guard, and called out `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunknown-pragmas"` directly.

Comment: Thanks @nneonneo. I'm experiencing it with other warnings too, like `-Wunused-variable` and `-Wunused-value`. I'd really like to get the `GCC pragma diagnostic` working rather than polluting the command line with options.

Comment: Why are folks closing as a duplicate? The problem here is with a number of warnings (`-Wunknown-pragmas`, `-Wunused-variable`, `-Wunused-value`), and adding additional options to the command line is not acceptable. The underlying problem is a GCC bug, and that's not even mentioned in the claimed duplicate.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in `gcc` at least. The following code:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunknown-pragmas"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wuninitialized"

int fn(void) {
    #pragma xyzzy
    int x;
    return x;
}

int main (void) {
    return fn();
}
```

has no problems ignoring the uninitialised `x` value but still complains about the pragma (without the `uninitialized` pragma, it generates a warning for `x` as you'd expect).

If you change the command line options to be `-Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas`, then it ignores it just fine. That's okay for your specific case since you want it applied over your entire translation unit but it won't allow the fine-grained control that you would get from the `#pragma` method (if it worked).

---

I went to raise a bug report on GCC but found that it already exists ([#53431](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53431)).

While that specific bug has to do with `-Wundef`, a snippet in one of the comments indicates that it probably applies to all variants affecting the preprocessor (slightly modified for emphasis):

> The C++ parser lexes (*and* preprocesses) before handling the pragmas, whereas the C parser processes the pragmas as it sees them.
>
> We must somehow parse these pragmas *also* in `cp/parser.c:631`. Maybe one can do something similar to what we do for `cp_parser_initial_pragma`, but within the loop and only handling pragma diagnostic. Surely, it will need some trial and error to get it right. If any of you wants to give it a try and need some help, just ask here or in the mailing list.

That explains why we don't see the same problem with `-Wuninitialized`, because it's detected during later stages of the compilation process, after the pragmas have been activated at the end of preprocessing.

So, if you want to see it fixed in a more timely manner (it was raised over three years ago), I'd suggest (as I have) hassling the GCC bugzilla site to try get some exposure.

---

***Update:*** Based on the linked bug report, it looks like this issue will be fixed in `gcc-13` but, as of yet, no ETA on that release. As of [Feb 22, 2023](https://gcc.gnu.org/pipermail/gcc/2023-February/240765.html), status is as follows:

> The GCC development branch which will become GCC 13 is in regression and documentation fixing mode (Stage 4) until we reach zero P1 regressions and branch for the release.
>
> We are making slow progress towards this goal, new bugs are coming in at a high pace.
>
> Please help triaging UNCONFIRMED reported regressions and at least provide some analysis for bugs attributed to you or in the area of your expertise when they are classified as target bugs.
>
> Quality Data:
>
> | Priority | Count | Change |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | P1 | 32 | -5 |
> | P2 | 492 | -5 |
> | P3 | 77 | -11 |
> | P4 | 255 | -1 |
> | P5 | 24 |  |
> | Total P1-P3 | 601 | -21 |
> | Total | 880 | -22 |

So, if you want to see this fixed in a more timely manner, please get involved in the process, even if that's only providing more information on the serious (P1) issues.

Comment: Yeah, the bigger problem is this is library code. So we need to fix it for working on the library itself. Its a convenience item for us. But users expect it to "just work" when they include the library. If they include the library and then have to jump through command line hoops because things don't work, then that's a problem.

Comment: @jww, if you're releasing a library (`.o/.a/.so/etc`), then the warning will not occur surely. Or is your library actually composed of compilable source?

Comment: Yes, the sources are released. Plus, some headers produce warnings, and we attempt to silence them with the same method.

Comment: @jww, went to raise a bug and found out it was raised some three years ago. See the update.

Comment: Now related: [GCC warns of Unknown Pragma for OpenMP, even though it support it](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66943). This is a secondary issue. I would ***really*** like the primary issue of `pragma GCC diagnostic` to be fixed.

Comment: 5 years later... 

Comment: 7 years later... 

Comment: @DimoMarkov, now slated for gcc 13 but no ETA as of yet.