# Ignoring note: offset of packed bit-field without using "-Wno-packed-bitfield-compat"

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc-warning, gcc4.4

I have this warning pop up when I'm trying to compile the following union:
`10:5: note: offset of packed bit-field 'main()::pack_it_in::<anonymous struct>::two' has changed in GCC 4.4`

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignore "-Wpacked-bitfield-compat"
union pack_it_in {
    struct
    {
        uint8_t zero : 3;
        uint8_t one : 2;
        uint8_t two : 6;
        uint8_t three : 4;
        uint8_t four : 1;
    } __attribute__((packed)) u8_2;
    uint16_t u16;
};
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

#pragma does not ignore that note. Is there a way to make #pragma work without having to use `-Wno-packed-bitfield-compat` since I want this warning ignored only for two of my eight unions?

Comment: A [likely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31509434/102441) about warning silencing not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just ran into a similar issue. It seems that gcc just doesn't like bitfields that cross the width of the type (as `two` does in the example)?

If you change all the types to `uint16_t`, gcc accepts:

```
union pack_it_in {
    struct
    {
        uint16_t zero  : 3;
        uint16_t one   : 2;
        uint16_t two   : 6;
        uint16_t three : 4;
        uint16_t four  : 1;
    } __attribute__((packed)) u8_2;
    uint16_t u16;
};
```

The layout is what you want it to be, even if the types of these members may not be.

Answer (score -2):

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wpacked-bitfield-compat"
union pack_it_in {
    struct
    {
        uint8_t zero : 3;
        uint8_t one : 2;
        uint8_t two : 6;
        uint8_t three : 4;
        uint8_t four : 1;
    } __attribute__((packed)) u8_2;
    uint16_t u16;
};
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Comment: Please don't just post code alone - it would be helpful if you explained how it works as well.