# g++ complains of #pragma region if I use #pragma GCC diagnostic

Tags: c++, linux, g++, pragma

I need to disable warning in an include file.

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor"
<some function>
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

however in the main.cpp file which includes the above .h file I use

```
#pragma region class_definitions
```

*I know it is "not standard pragma" - I use it to control huge amount of declarations in the main file as I use VS for editing code, before I go to linux*

So I get this warning (which does NOT appear if I dont use `#pragma GCC diagnostic push/pop`)

```
warning: ignoring ‘#pragma region class_definitions’ [-Wunknown-pragmas]
```

Is there a way to have a cake AND eat it?

**EDIT:** *I tried this and the warning still shows*

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunknown-pragmas"
#pragma region class_definitions
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Comment: You could disable the warning, `-Wno-unknown-pragmas`

Comment: I dont want that either. I need to know if a "truly" unknown pragma appears in the code

Comment: Then you could wrap a `#pragma GCC diagnostic` *blah blah* around each `#pragma region` to disable the warning for the actually expected other-platform pragma.  (I'm not sure if a region pragma can be replaced with the `__pragma(region)`, but if it can then the other platform could `#define __pragma(x)` to nothing.)

Comment: I tried the first suggestion. didnt work. I edited the question

Comment: Looks like a GCC bug, consider reporting it.

Comment: @Eljay - tried `__pragma` - it doesnt show a warning anymore. But VS doesnt recognise it as a `region` - I cant collapse it.. Ok neverming. Seems like a waste of time!

Comment: `#ifdef _MSC_VER` around each pragma may be a workaround for what appears to be a GCC bug.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55069333/cannot-temporarily-disable-unknown-pragmas-warning-in-gcc

Comment: why I never find these things when I google?! :)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842306/suppress-wunknown-pragmas-warning-in-gcc and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31509434/gcc-does-not-honor-pragma-gcc-diagnostic-to-silence-warnings P.S. There is no such thing as standard pragma in C++. All pragmas are implementation defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faked #pragma region as follows.

```
#ifndef __PRAGMAREGION__ // Sign commands
... code goes here ...
#endif // Sign commands
```

VSCode does collapse/expand in the same way as #pragma region; and the GCC compiler is fine with it.

Not perfect... but the VSCode collapse feature is too important to lose.