# Avoid false-positive -Wswitch warnings

Tags: c, enums

Let's have a list of values (foo.lst):

```
foo,
bar,
baz,
```

Let's make an enum out of this

```
enum foo {
  #include "foo.lst"
  _foo_length
};
```

Let's use that enum in a `switch`:

```
int main(void) {
  enum foo[_foo_length];

  switch(f[0]) {
    case foo: return 0;
    case bar: return 0;
    case baz: return 0;
  }

  __builtin_unreachable();
}
```

(this code is dumb, but just ignore that)

The problem:
With `-Wswitch` (included in `-Wall`), GCC and Clang (and probably others) will warn:

> warning: enumeration value '_foo_length' not handled in switch [-Wswitch]

Solutions:

- Disabling `-Wno-switch` hides that warning.
  Downside: we lose warnings about any other `case` missing from the switch.
- Adding a `default: unreachable();` case.
  Downside: we lose compile-time warnings of missing cases, in favour of a runtime crash if we ever hit one of the missing cases when debugging.
- Replacing the last value of the enum with a `#define _foo_length (baz + 1)`, making it not part of the enum anymore.
  Downside: it requires that define to be manually updated every time a value is added to the list. Someone will invariably forget, breaking everything.

Ideally, there should be a way to **mark an enum's value as no being assignable**, thereby making it not produce a warning in the compiler when reading the possible values and this one isn't there, without requiring a preprocessor macro needing duplicate modifications.

Is there anything like that? Any other option I didn't think of?

Comment: Since you're creating the enum dynamically, how can you be sure that the `switch` really covers all the cases?

Comment: And what happens if the file doesn't have one of the cases? This whole thing smells wrong to me.

Comment: You can add a `case _foo_length:`

Comment: @Barmar - (To your first comment) Isn't that exactly the rationale behind `-Wswitch`?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth `-Wswitch` performs the opposite test. If `foo.lst` is missing one of the names, he'll get an undefined variable error. But I wonder why he would hard-code names in a `switch` when he's loading the names dynamically, there seems to be a design error there.

Comment: AFAIK there is no gcc switch that can say: `don't warn me if I didn't include XXX in the switch but I want to be warned for all other enum values`

Comment: I'm not sure this will help but maybe it could be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3378560/4386427

Comment: @Barmar: OliverCharlesworth is right, the whole point of -Wswitch is to warn if a case listed in the file but not handled in one of the switches. The opposite case wouldn't happen in my situation, but if it did, it would just result in a compile error (unknown symbol).

Comment: And yes @Barmar, `case _foo_length: break;` is a good solution I hadn't though of, although a bit verbose (has to be in each and every `switch`). Post this as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
case _foo_length:
    unreachable();
    break;
```

so that all the cases will be handled. You could create a macro for it to keep it from being so verbose.