# GCC 7, -Wimplicit-fallthrough warnings, and portable way to clear them?

Tags: c++, gcc, switch-statement, warnings

We are catching warnings from GCC 7 for implicit fall through in a switch statement. Previously, we cleared them under Clang (that's the reason for the comment seen below):

```
g++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -c authenc.cpp
asn.cpp: In member function ‘void EncodedObjectFilter::Put(const byte*, size_t)’:
asn.cpp:359:18: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
    m_state = BODY;  // fall through
                  ^
asn.cpp:361:3: note: here
   case BODY:
   ^~~~
```

The [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) states to use `__attribute__ ((fallthrough))`, but its not portable. The manual also states *"... it is also possible to add a fallthrough comment to silence the warning"*, but it only offer `FALLTHRU` (is this really the only choice?):

```
switch (cond)
  {
  case 1:
    bar (0);
    /* FALLTHRU */
  default:
    …
  }
```

Is there a portable way to clear the fall through warning for both Clang and GCC? If so, then what is it?

Comment: As you are using C++17 see attribute `[[fallthrough]];` (note - needs the `;`) source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes

Comment: Thanks Richard. Unfortunately, NO, we are not attributes at the moment. We are still supporting back to C++03. `-std=c++17` is just testing one configuration under Fedora 26 because it supplies GCC 7. But I would entertain a macro to abstract it for portability.

Comment: Maybe `BOOST_FALLTHROUGH` does what you need. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html

Comment: Thanks @BaummitAugen - Yeah, that could probably work. Would you happen to know if `__has_feature(x)` works for this? Is it enough to test with `__has_feature(fallthrough)`? Or do we need to do this with compiler version tests? Or maybe something else?

Comment: As far as I understood the docs, you just put `BOOST_FALLTHROUGH;` in your code and then it just expands to the right thing to cancel the warning. If the compiler in use warns, but does not have a way to silence the warning, there's nothing we can do anyways I guess.

Comment: @BaummitAugen - My bad, we don't use Boost. I've got to build an equivalent macro from scratch. That's what the additional questions were about.

Comment: I would guess this will require some compiler version tests, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

GCC expects the marker comment on its own line, like this:

```
  m_state = BODY;
  // fall through
case BODY:
```

The marker also has to come right before the `case` label; there cannot be an intervening closing brace `}`.

`fall through` is among the markers recognized by GCC.  It's not just `FALLTHRU`.  For a full list, see the documentation of the [`-Wimplicit-fallthrough` option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wimplicit-fallthrough).  Also see this [posting on the Red Hat Developer blog](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/03/10/wimplicit-fallthrough-in-gcc-7/).

C++17 adds a [`[[fallthrough]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/fallthrough) attribute that can be used to suppress such warnings.  Note the trailing semicolon:

```
  m_state = BODY;
  [[fallthrough]];
case BODY:
```

Clang supports `-Wimplicit-fallthrough` warnings, but does not enable them as part of `-Wall` or `-Wextra`. Clang does not recognize comment markers, so the attribute-based suppression has to be used for it (which currently means the non-standard `__attribute__((fallthrough))` construct for the C front end).

Note that suppressing the warning with marker comments only works if the compiler actually sees the comment.  If the preprocessor runs separately, it needs to be instructed to preserve comments, as with the [`-C` option of GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-C).  For example, to avoid spurious warnings with [ccache](https://ccache.samba.org/), you need to specify the `-C` flag when compiling, or, with recent versions of ccache, use the `keep_comments_cpp` option.

Comment: Thanks Florian. I tried GCC 7 on Fedora 26 (`gcc (GCC) 7.1.1 20170622 (Red Hat 7.1.1-3)`). Moving `// fall through` to the bottom as shown in your example still produced the warning. Here is the real source file in case its needed: [`asn.cpp`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/asn.cpp#L359). If it matters, I am using `-std=c++17`.

Comment: Where exactly did you place the comment?  Before or after the `}`?  You need to place it on the line immediately before the `case` keyword.

Comment: Thanks again Florian. Yep, you're right... The `// fall through` was inside the closing brace. I just realized it myself, and came back to accept your answer after testing things the way they were intended. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks again Florian. It appears others are having some issues with GCC's implementation. See [-Wimplicit-fallthrough broken?](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2017-07/msg00059.html) on the GCC Help list.

Comment: FYI:  -save-temps option breaks the comment recognition heuristic. The warning is not suppressed in that case

Comment: Although fallthrough comments may be portable, comments in code are designed to not live through the preprocessor, and with a tool like ccache, that makes use of the preprocessor output, any such comments will be removed before the preprocessed output is sent to gcc for compilation. Hence, if you are using ccache, you will still see these warnings.

Comment: @BlueDemon, try ccache with `keep_comments_cpp` set to true. Does it help?

Comment: @Florian Weimer, keep_comments_cpp is a ccache 3.3 feature and since I'm using ccache 3.2.7 I don't know (yet). On monday, I will test it though. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Thanks, I must have botched my initial testing. Answer updated.

Comment: This does not work on gcc 9 -- a `// fall through` comment on a line by itself immediately before the next `case` does not supress the warning.

Answer (score 18):

**C++17 `[[fallthrough]]`**

Example:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    switch (argc) {
        case 0:
            argc = 1;
            [[fallthrough]];
        case 1:
            argc = 2;
    };
}
```

Compile with:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -Wimplicit-fallthrough main.cpp
```

If you remove the `[[fallthrough]];`, GCC warns:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:5:15: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
             argc = 1;
             ~~^~~
main.cpp:6:9: note: here
         case 1:
         ^~~~
```

Also note from the example that the warning only happens if you fall beacross two cases: the last case statement (`case 1` here) generates no warnings even though it has no `break`.

The following constructs don't generate the warning either:

```
#include <cstdlib>

[[noreturn]] void my_noreturn_func() {
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // Erm, an actual break
    switch (argc) {
        case 0:
            argc = 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            argc = 2;
    }

    // Return also works.
    switch (argc) {
        case 0:
            argc = 1;
            return 0;
        case 1:
            argc = 2;
    }

    // noreturn functions are also work.
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538291/what-is-the-point-of-noreturn/47444782#47444782
    switch (argc) {
        case 0:
            argc = 1;
            my_noreturn_func();
        case 1:
            argc = 2;
    }

    // Empty case synonyms are fine.
    switch (argc) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
            argc = 2;
    }

    // Magic comment mentioned at:
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/45137452/895245
    switch (argc) {
        case 0:
            argc = 1;
            // fall through
        case 1:
            argc = 2;
    }

    switch (argc) {
        // GCC extension for pre C++17.
        case 0:
            argc = 1;
            __attribute__ ((fallthrough));
        case 1:
            argc = 2;
    }

    switch (argc) {
        // GCC examines all braches.
        case 0:
            if (argv[0][0] == 'm') {
                [[fallthrough]];
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        case 1:
            argc = 2;
    }
}
```

We can see from the last one that GCC examines all possible branches, and warns if any of them don't have `[[fallthrough]];` or `break` or `return`.

You might also want to check for feature availability with macros as in [this GEM5 inspired snippet](https://github.com/gem5/gem5/blob/bb0ab1d464ff875b44cfce57e3c01c7587b02727/src/base/compiler.hh#L74):

```
#if defined __has_cpp_attribute
    #if __has_cpp_attribute(fallthrough)
        #define MY_FALLTHROUGH [[fallthrough]]
    #else
        #define MY_FALLTHROUGH
    #endif
#else
    #define MY_FALLTHROUGH
#endif
```

See also: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/fallthrough

Tested on GCC 7.4.0, Ubuntu 18.04.

**See also**

C version of this question: [How to do an explicit fall-through in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44511436/how-to-do-an-explicit-fall-through-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

Another example: The Linux kernel provides a [`fallthrough`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/process/deprecated.html?highlight=fallthrough#implicit-switch-case-fall-through) pseudo-keyword macro. Which can be used as:

```
switch (cond) {
case 1:
    foo();
    fallthrough;
case 2:
    bar();
    break;
default:
    baz();
}
```

In kernel [v5.10](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10/source/include/linux/compiler_attributes.h#L208) its implemented like this:

```
#if __has_attribute(__fallthrough__)
# define fallthrough                    __attribute__((__fallthrough__))
#else
# define fallthrough                    do {} while (0)  /* fallthrough */
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Clean C solution:

```
int r(int a) {
    switch(a) {
    case 0:
        a += 3;
    case 1:
        a += 2;
    default:
        a += a;
    }
    return a;
}
```

becomes:

```
int h(int a) {
    switch(a) {
    case 0:
        a += 3;
        goto one;
    case 1:
    one:
        a += 2;
        goto others;
    default:
    others:
        a += a;
    }
    return a;
}
```

EDIT: Moved the labels after case statements, as suggested by Stéphane Gourichon in comments, to see the fallthrough more easily.

Comment: I like the idea because it is fully portable. Is it really effective to put the extra label *before* the `case` ? Technically there is still a fallthrough. I would consider instead things like : `goto one` then `case 1:` then `one:` in that order. Gcc accepts both variants.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody mentioned disabling the warning altogether and this might not be the answer the OP was looking for but I think it should be included for completeness since it also works for both compilers:

`-Wno-implicit-fallthrough`

If for some reason you are not able to change the source code, this keeps the compile output clean allowing for a clear view on other problems (but of course one has to be aware of what one loses).

Comment: If there is one thing that is more annoying than no oversight then it is overreaching oversight enabled by a bad rule set. Compiler warnings are one such example.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wimplicit-fallthrough"
// your code
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```