# How to use __attribute__((fallthrough)) correctly in gcc

Tags: c, gcc, switch-statement, fall-through

Code sample:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    switch(argc)
    {
    case 0:
        argc = 5;
        __attribute__((fallthrough));

    case 1:
        break;
    }
}
```

[Using gcc 6.3.0](https://godbolt.org/g/5n69P1), with `-std=c11` only, this code gives a warning:

```
<source>: In function 'main':
7 : <source>:7:3: warning: empty declaration
   __attribute__((fallthrough));
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What is the correct way to use this without eliciting a warning?

Comment: If you compare [the 6.4 documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.4.0/gcc/) and [the 7.1 documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.1.0/gcc/), it seems statement attributes like that was added in version 7.

Comment: Not an answer, but the 6.3 manual completely lacks the "statement attribute' section that is present in 7.1, where `fallthrough` is described. I'm thinking it's simply not supported for 6.3. The diagnostic is because GCC doesn't simply ignore the unknown attribute, and sees it as a declaration [that violates this constraint](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7p2)

Comment: @StoryTeller that makes sense

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As previously answered, `__attribute__ ((fallthrough))` was introduced in **GCC 7**. 
To maintain backward compatibility and clear the *fall through* warning for both Clang and GCC, you can use the `/* fall through */` [marker comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45129741/gcc-7-wimplicit-fallthrough-warnings-and-portable-way-to-clear-them).

Applied to your code sample:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    switch(argc)
    {
    case 0:
        argc = 5;
        /* fall through */

    case 1:
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Both the marker comment or attribute can be use after the code on the same line, or below.

Comment: Not without a warning. With the attribute `warning: empty declaration` will be returned on older GCC versions (< 7.x).

Comment: Sorry, the GCC7 was implied.

Comment: The fall though comment is horrible compiler design, Combined preprocessing and compiling and combiling the same file after it's been preprocessed separately should produce the same warnings/errors, but that can't work if you have special magic comments.

Answer (score 8):

Tried to comment previous, but did not have 50 reputation.

So, my experiences:

1) the feature is since gcc 7, so using **attribute** on older
compilers will give warning. therefore I currently use:

```
#if defined(__GNUC__) && __GNUC__ >= 7
 #define FALL_THROUGH __attribute__ ((fallthrough))
#else
 #define FALL_THROUGH ((void)0)
#endif /* __GNUC__ >= 7 */
```

and then I use `FALL_THROUGH;` in code

(Some day I figure out what is needed for clang, but not today)

2) I spent considerable time to try to get the gcc *marker comment* to work, but nothing I tried worked! Some comment somewere suggested that in order for that to work one has to add `-C` to
`gcc` arguments (meaning comments will be passed to `cc1`). Sure gcc 7 documentation doesn't mention anything about this requirement...

Comment: For XCode 12 compatibility (along with GNU GCC >= 7 compatibility), I used a variation of your solution: `#if defined(__GNUC__) && __GNUC__ >= 7 || defined(__clang__) && __clang_major__ >= 12`. On XCode 12 `$ gcc -xc -dM -E /dev/null | sort | grep __GNUC__` yields  `#define __GNUC__ 4`.

Comment: good information -- will integrate to my "templates" :D

Comment: Clang actually supports this since version 10 so `__clang_major__ >= 10` is more accurate. It seems this was missed in the release notes but the commit is here: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/1e0affb6e564b7361b0aadb38805f26deff4ecfc

Comment: I tried with `__cland_major__>=10` and got the issue of "declaration does not declare anything"

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the code below, because only this one works for me on Android:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wimplicit-fallthrough"
// your code
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```