# fallthrough in case with different standards in GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, c++14

There is a code which needs to be compiled with C++17 as well as with an earlier standards. Compiler: GCC.
I've tried to use different techniques for a different standards. Those works fine separately (without if-else: c++17 - with attribute, c++14 - with a comment) , but if I try to use those together, in one if-else, it's failed.

There should no be "break" keyword, this is an expected logic for the case.

```
case 10:
    if (/* some condition */) {
    // ... some processing 
       break;
    }
    #if __cplusplus >= 201703L
        [[fallthrough]];
    #else
        /* fall through */
    #endif
default:
// ... other processing
```

The build with c++14 fails with an error like no "else" branch there:

> error: this statement may fall through [-Werror=implicit-fallthrough=]

any idea why it happens

Comment: Did you try using [the `__attribute__` alternative](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wimplicit-fallthrough)? An earlier question here suggests that the comment must immediately precede the `case` to be effective. It's possible that the intervening `#endif` disqualifies it.

Comment: yes, gcc-specific attribute works fine, just would like to understand what is wrong with an if-else. do you mean that comment version should be BEFORE the case? if I remove if-else with c++17 attribute and keep the comment on the same place as for now, it works fine

Comment: It should immediately precede case/default. Here you have an intervening `#endif` stuck in between. A simple Google search found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45129741/) whose first answer gives more details.

Comment: Compile fine [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/xMnG84bdo)

Comment: I see , thank you! then I'll look for the issue in my compilation flags/conditions

Comment: Why don't you just use the comment for all versions?

Comment: yes, you are right, comment version is a solution for all GCC standards.