# My switch statement is not working in C++

Tags: c++

I should be getting a day of the week. 0 should be monday and 6 should be sunday.I don't know if it's run time error or what. I have tried everything that I can think of.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
string getDayOfWeek(int dayNum){
    string dayName;
    switch (dayNum){
    case 0:
        dayName = "Sunday";
        break;
    case 1:
        dayName = "Monday";
        break;
    case 2:
        dayName = "Tuesday";
        break;
    case 3:
        dayName = "Wednesday";
        break;
    case 4:
        dayName = "Thursday";
        break;
    case 5:
        dayName = "Friday";
        break;
    case 6:
        dayName = "Saturday";
        break;
    default:
        dayName = "Invalid Day Number!";
    }
}

int main()
{
  cout << getDayOfWeek(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not returning anything. Put `return dayName;` after your `switch` statement.

Comment: Or just `return` in each `case` instead of assigning the result to a variable and `break`ing.

Comment: btw this is the schoolbook example of why you should pay attention to compiler warnings

Comment: Python? octave? sql?

Comment: This duplicate is wrong. The duplicate is about attempting to switch on a string. But OP is correctly switching on an `int` and assigning to the string in the cases within, his mistake is a different one.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux See https://stackoverflow.com/q/57532056/10957435: It may be better to return at the end of the function.

Comment: @Chipster I don't see how adding a `return` at the end changes whether you also `return` in the `case`s. In fact, that's what the accepted answer in the linked question does.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I must misunderstand. The accepted answer avoids UB by returning at the end of the function if none in the switch is found. That's all I'm trying to say.

Comment: @Chipster I'm assuming your first comment was in response to my first comment. To me, *"It may be better to return at the end of the function"* seems to imply that you are proposing a better alternative to what I propose. What I don't see is why the two are incompatible. It seems to me that the two are orthogonal and unrelated. Whether you `break` or `return` in each `case` doesn't change how you handle the scenario where no `case` is selected. Did you specifically mean to say that `return` after the `switch` is better than a `default`?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Looking back, I misread your first comment. That is exactly what I meant to say..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your function `std::string getDayOfWeek(int dayNum)` needs to `return` a `std::string`.

You can do that right in your `switch` statement:

```
std::string getDayOfWeek(int dayNum){
    switch (dayNum){
    case 0:
        return "Sunday";
    case 1:
        return "Monday";
    case 2:
        return "Tuesday";
    case 3:
        return "Wednesday";
    case 4:
        return "Thursday";
    case 5:
        return "Friday";
    case 6:
        return "Saturday";
    default:
        return "Invalid Day Number!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is in my opinion the correct fix for the OP. Nice and clear and simple. +1

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to print `Monday` in the above given example, but there is no `return` statement in the `getDayOfWeek()` function. Please add `return dayName;` and try again.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a `return` value for a non-`void` function. That's *undefined behaviour*. Plus your indexing is incorrect if you want `0` to be `Monday` which your question wording states.

Why not use simply

```
#include <algorithm> // for std::min
#include <string> // for std::string
const std::string& getDayOfWeek(unsigned dayNum){
    static std::string data[] = {
        "Monday",
        "Tuesday",
        "Wednesday",
        "Thursday",
        "Friday",
        "Saturday",
        "Sunday",
        "Invalid Day Number!"
    };
    return data[std::min(dayNum, 7u)];
}
```

noting that (i) the returned reference never dangles since the `static` array is valid for the lifetime of the program, and (ii) an implicit conversion to an `unsigned` type permits error handling on only one edge?

Comment: @Bathsheba Nevermind about the `const` thing I mentioned, I was confused. I was thinking `getDayOfWeek` returns a `std::string &` and `data` was `const`, which is the opposite.

Comment: I'm guessing that it's starting with Sunday to be `struct tm` compatible.

Comment: `const_cast<std::string&>(getDayOfWeek(0)) = "Legal hack";` unless `data` is made `const`?

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone. I'm new to programming but I do notice that its such a schoolboy mistake.

Comment: @RealG when I wrote "schoolbook example" I didnt mean that it is a mistake only schoolboys make. Rather the opposite, it is a mistake I make all the time, I bet it is so common also for other coders that it could appear in a schoolbook as a good example for why warnings are important