# Selectively silence warning for unhandled enum values

Tags: c++, gcc

The project I work on have things like the following:

```
enum SomeType {
    value_100     = 100,
    reserved_101  = 101,
    value_102     = 102
};
```

The presence of these 'reserved' identifiers, is not something the
powers to be are willing to change.

I would like to adorn them somehow, something similar to 
`[[maybe_unused]]`, so I can turn on `-Werror=switch`

This is a huge (and old) codebase, refactor to not use switches would
be a major undertaking, not something on the table right now.

Is there some way to selectively silence warnings regarding
unhandled enumeration values in gcc? Note that I still want the warnings
for enumeration values not so adorned. Using a gcc extension would be ok.

Comment: Probably a pragma. Have you tried the docs? Or search? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378560/how-to-disable-gcc-warnings-for-a-few-lines-of-code

Comment: Please specify if you want a global option or it's ok to do minimal modification of switch-cases in question.

Comment: @yugr Could a modification of the switch-cases work?

Comment: @sp2danny Well, you could just define `IGNORE_DEFAULTS` macro which would contain `case reserved_1: ... case reserved_LAST: break;` and add it to all switches in question. Addition itself could also be automated via simple Perl script. I'm afraid that's your only chance as there's _no_ flag/pragma to control application of `-Wswitch`.