# Using -Wtype-limits with type generic code

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++14

I have a function that performs a negative check on a value of a generic type (well I don't want to assume the type, it is not necessarily templated). However, with `-Wtype-limits` enabled, the compiler complains about the negative check if the type in question is an unsigned type. Removing the negative check is a bad idea if the type might change to be a signed type, and disabling the warnings is not ideal, as it might catch legitimate issues.

```
using example_t = uint8_t;   // could be int8_t or int64_t or really whatever integer type that can store values 0 - 8.

void example(example_t value) {
    if (value < 0 || value >= 9) {  // <-- errors on the 'value < 0' check
        throw std::invalid_argument("some error message");
    }
    // continue processing ...
}
```

Even if I use C++17 and use `if constexpr(std::is_unsigned<example_t>::value)`  to guard the check that is warning, it still warns. I've noticed that GCC does not emit warning for `if constexpr`'d out code if it would trigger warnings because the value assigned into variables of those type would fall out of the range of the type. Also, GCC emits the warning even if I cast it to a `signed int` first. The warning behavior is not consistent with itself, so this seems like a bug. Clang issues no warning at all for these types of checks.

But I wondering if there was a way around this, my code base is strictly C++14 compliant, and we are stuck with old GCC compilers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure it is worth the impact on readability, but you can move the comparison into a template context using a generic lambda. GCC doesn't warn about this in the templated code:

```
if ([](auto v){return v < 0;}(value) || value >= 9)
```

---

or maybe better write a function:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_negative(T t) { return t < 0; }
```

and use that:

```
if (is_negative(value) || value >= 9)
```

---

or just using `std::less` also wont warn:

```
if (std::less()(value, 0) || value >= 9)
```

---

GCC also has `#pragma`s to disable warnings temporarily, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378560/how-to-disable-gcc-warnings-for-a-few-lines-of-code):

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wtype-limits"
if (value < 0 || value >= 9) {
    throw std::invalid_argument("some error message");
}
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Comment: The `is_negative` approach seems like the best option for me. More readable than the lambdas (and works in constexpr functions in C++14) and more portable than pragmas.

Comment: @ktb Ah yes, I forgot that lambdas were allowed in constant expressions only since C++17. The `std::less` approach should also be usable in constant expressions in C++14.