# C++ API for LLVM library generates too many warnings

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, llvm, llvm-c++-api

I am not sure if I am the only person or this is the problem of so many other people.

What I suffer from is that for an even simple code that includes `LLVM` headers regardless of what ever I write in my main function, I get too many warnings when I compile my codes with extra warnings:

```
#include <llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h>
#include <llvm/IR/Verifier.h>
#include <llvm/Support/TargetSelect.h>
#include <llvm/ExecutionEngine/ExecutionEngine.h>
#include <llvm/IR/Instructions.h>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I cat get these warnings by using either `gcc` or `clang`:

> g++-9 -std=c++17 main.cpp -Wall -Wextra -I/usr/lib/llvm-9/include -c -o main.o

> clang++-9 -std=c++17 main.cpp -Wall -Wextra -I/usr/lib/llvm-9/include -c -o main.o

They are mainly unused parameters:

```
In file included from /usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/IR/ConstantFolder.h:20,
                 from /usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h:24,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/IR/Constants.h: In member function ‘llvm::Value* llvm::ConstantData::handleOperandChangeImpl(llvm::Value*, llvm::Value*)’:
/usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/IR/Constants.h:60:41: warning: unused parameter ‘From’ [-Wunused-parameter]
   60 |   Value *handleOperandChangeImpl(Value *From, Value *To) {
      |                                  ~~~~~~~^~~~
/usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/IR/Constants.h:60:54: warning: unused parameter ‘To’ [-Wunused-parameter]
   60 |   Value *handleOperandChangeImpl(Value *From, Value *To) {
      |                                               ~~~~~~~^~
In file included from /usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/IR/ConstantFolder.h:21,
                 from /usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h:24,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/IR/InstrTypes.h: In member function ‘bool llvm::CallBase::isFnAttrDisallowedByOpBundle(llvm::StringRef) const’:
/usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/IR/InstrTypes.h:1913:47: warning: unused parameter ‘S’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 1913 |   bool isFnAttrDisallowedByOpBundle(StringRef S) const {
      |                                     ~~~~~~~~~~^
In file included from /usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h:33,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/IR/Instructions.h: In member function ‘llvm::BasicBlock* llvm::ReturnInst::getSuccessor(unsigned int) const’:
/usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/IR/Instructions.h:2943:37: warning: unused parameter ‘idx’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 2943 |   BasicBlock *getSuccessor(unsigned idx) const {
      |                            ~~~~~~~~~^~~
...
```

I just truncate these warnings. They are too many.
When I turn on the `-Wconversion` the problem becomes even worse:

```
In file included from /usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/Support/MathExtras.h:17,
                 from /usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/ADT/SmallVector.h:19,
                 from /usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/ADT/STLExtras.h:20,
                 from /usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/ADT/StringRef.h:12,
                 from /usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/ADT/StringMap.h:16,
                 from /usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/Support/Host.h:16,
                 from /usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/ADT/Hashing.h:48,
                 from /usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/ADT/ArrayRef.h:12,
                 from /usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h:18,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/Support/SwapByteOrder.h: In function ‘uint16_t llvm::sys::SwapByteOrder_16(uint16_t)’:
/usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/Support/SwapByteOrder.h:36:23: warning: conversion from ‘int’ to ‘uint16_t’ {aka ‘short unsigned int’} may change value [-Wconversion]
   36 |   uint16_t Hi = value << 8;
      |                 ~~~~~~^~~~
/usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/Support/SwapByteOrder.h:37:23: warning: conversion from ‘int’ to ‘uint16_t’ {aka ‘short unsigned int’} may change value [-Wconversion]
   37 |   uint16_t Lo = value >> 8;
      |                 ~~~~~~^~~~
In file included from /usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/ADT/STLExtras.h:20,
                 from /usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/ADT/StringRef.h:12,
                 from /usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/ADT/StringMap.h:16,
                 from /usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/Support/Host.h:16,
                 from /usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/ADT/Hashing.h:48,
                 from /usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/ADT/ArrayRef.h:12,
                 from /usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h:18,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/ADT/SmallVector.h: In constructor ‘llvm::SmallVectorBase::SmallVectorBase(void*, size_t)’:
/usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/ADT/SmallVector.h:45:35: warning: conversion from ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} to ‘unsigned int’ may change value [-Wconversion]
   45 |       : BeginX(FirstEl), Capacity(TotalCapacity) {}
      |                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
```

I get these warnings by `clang` too:

```
...
In file included from main.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h:18:
In file included from /usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/ADT/ArrayRef.h:12:
/usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/ADT/Hashing.h:190:15: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'const char' to 'uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') [-Wsign-conversion]
  uint8_t a = s[0];
          ~   ^~~~
/usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/ADT/Hashing.h:191:15: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'const char' to 'uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') [-Wsign-conversion]
  uint8_t b = s[len >> 1];
          ~   ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/ADT/Hashing.h:192:15: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'const char' to 'uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') [-Wsign-conversion]
  uint8_t c = s[len - 1];
          ~   ^~~~~~~~~~
...
```

This is just a MWE. Adding more headers, I can get other types of warnings such as

```
/usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/ADT/Twine.h:232:16: warning: ‘<anonymous>.llvm::Twine::RHS.llvm::Twine::Child::twine’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
           !RHS.twine->isBinary())
            ~~~~^~~~~
```

---

Now, I am wondering whether `LLVM` is written carelessly? I always turn on all warnings and make sure my application compiles with 0 warnings. When I do this while using `LLVM` all warnings of my  code are burried under `LLVM` ones. I cannot easily see them. Usually the first advise from people is to turn off those warnings switches. I strictly resist that. I want to find them for my application. The alternative solution comes to my mind is to turn off these warnings only for `LLVM` but not for my application. Is this possible especially when using `CMake`?

Comment: Your will probably find it easy to get a patch for this merged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue of system header files causing warnings is a common one. It is not really for me to judge whether the authors of those headers were "careless" or not, but there is a relatively simple way to disable specific warnings before including the 'offending' headers, then restore your 'full' warnings once they have been included.

For **clang** you can do this with various `#pragma diagnostic ...` lines, as shown in the following code snippet:

```cpp
#if defined (__clang__)
#pragma clang diagnostic push // Saves current diagnostic settings
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wsign-conversion" // Ignore this warning
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-parameter" // and this one...
    // ... Add similar lines for other warnings you wish to disable
#endif

// Now include the 'offending' headers ...
#include <llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h>
#include <llvm/IR/Verifier.h>
#include <llvm/Support/TargetSelect.h>
#include <llvm/ExecutionEngine/ExecutionEngine.h>
#include <llvm/IR/Instructions.h>

#if defined(__clang__)
#pragma clang diagnostic pop // Restores the saved settings
#endif
```

I don't have access to a GCC compiler but I *believe* very similar directives can be used: just substitute `GCC` for `clang` in the lines where that occurs. More information on such `#pragma` directives (for the GCC versions) can be found [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html).

Comment: This got me on the right track to solve it with the GCC compiler. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378560/how-to-disable-gcc-warnings-for-a-few-lines-of-code

Answer (score 1):

It is dependent on your GCC/clang/OS installation. On Fedora 32 it works as expected out of the box with system `gcc-10.2.1-1.fc32.x86_64` + system `clang-10.0.0-2.fc32.x86_64`:

```
#include <llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h>
#include <llvm/IR/Verifier.h>
#include <llvm/Support/TargetSelect.h>
#include <llvm/ExecutionEngine/ExecutionEngine.h>
#include <llvm/IR/Instructions.h>

static void func(int val) {}

int main()
{
    func(42);
    return 0;
}
```

For GCC:

```
$ g++ -o stackoverflowllvmwarnings stackoverflowllvmwarnings.C $(llvm-config --cflags --libs) -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra
stackoverflowllvmwarnings.C: In function ‘void func(int)’:
stackoverflowllvmwarnings.C:7:22: warning: unused parameter ‘val’ [-Wunused-parameter]
    7 | static void func(int val) {}
      |                  ~~~~^~~
$ _
```

For clang:

```
$ clang++ -o stackoverflowllvmwarnings stackoverflowllvmwarnings.C $(llvm-config --cflags --libs) -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra
stackoverflowllvmwarnings.C:7:22: warning: unused parameter 'val' [-Wunused-parameter]
static void func(int val) {}
                     ^
1 warning generated.
$ _
```

If you really want (you do not) the warnings even for system headers use `Wsystem-headers` (it works similar way both for gcc and clang):

```
$ clang++ -o stackoverflowllvmwarnings stackoverflowllvmwarnings.C $(llvm-config --cflags --libs) -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Wsystem-headers
In file included from stackoverflowllvmwarnings.C:1:
In file included from /usr/include/llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h:17:
In file included from /usr/include/llvm-c/Types.h:17:
In file included from /usr/include/llvm-c/DataTypes.h:28:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/../../../../include/c++/10/cmath:42:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/../../../../include/c++/10/bits/cpp_type_traits.h:110:12: warning: keyword '__is_void' will be made available as an identifier for the remainder of the translation unit [-Wkeyword-compat]
    struct __is_void
           ^
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for proposing system headers. You probably mean `-isystem`. The problem is that I have some `-I./my-local-folder` and their related warning will be ignored too. But, maybe for some others, this will not be a problem.

Comment: One can be experimenting with -isystem etc. but that is a job of system integrators. I have shown it just works. One can also cross-compile to W32/W64 by MinGW or what other targets are needed.