# Make gcc to skip "-Werror=unused-parameter" for a specific .cpp file

Tags: c++, gcc

Is there any way in C++ to make the g++ to skip "-Werror=unused-parameter" errors for a specific .cpp file?

Example:

```
int foo(int a, int b)
{
    a++;
    std::cout << "b is not used in this function";
    return a*a;
}
```

Comment: By compiling these file(s) with a separate command with this warning disabled. How to do that depends on the building system you use.

Comment: Could you provide have an example of code with some detailled output please? :)

Comment: The [`[[maybe_unused]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused) attribute might help.

Comment: I presume this is a duplicate, although for this warning, I'd prefer `[[maybe_unused]]`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378560

Comment: -Wno-unused-variable use this switch

Comment: @Jean-Benoit Harvey added.

Comment: @DrewDormann Yes you are right. That's what I was looking for. I saw it somewhere before but forgot it. Thanks.