# Check for infinity while using -Wfloat-equal?

Tags: c, floating-point

My pet project uses `-nostdlib` so I can't use any C libraries however I can include them for constants.

Below is my code. If I compile using `gcc -Wfloat-equal -nostdlib -O2 -c a.c` on gcc or clang it'll give me the error below. I was curious if there's a way to check without triggering this warning. I suspect I can't unless I call code I don't compile

> warning: comparing floating-point with ‘==’ or ‘!=’ is unsafe [-Wfloat-equal]

```
#include <math.h>
int IsInfinity(double d) {
    return d != (double)INFINITY && (float)d == INFINITY;
}
```

Comment: Not saying this is wise, but can you cast everything to `uint64_t`?

Comment: So you want this warning *unless* you're comparing with `INFINITY`?

Comment: @Barmar really I'm just going through all my warnings using -Weverything, that was one of them. I disabled a few warnings but thought maybe I can leave that on

Comment: [How to disable GCC warnings for a few lines of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378560/how-to-disable-gcc-warnings-for-a-few-lines-of-code) could be useful.

Comment: Use `d < INFINITY`.

Comment: @Henry What should `IsInfinity(-INFINITY)` return?

Comment: @Henry B, Please report what result you want for `+INFINITY, -INFINITY, +DBL_MAX, -DBL_MAX`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica turns out my use case never uses negatives. I completely didn't realize it was unhandled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `return d < INFINITY && (float) d >= INFINITY;`.

Another option is `return isfinite(d) && isinf((float) d);` if you want to classify negative values symmetrically. (These are macros defined in `math.h`.)

Answer (score 0):

Code looks like it is trying to test if `d` is in the finite range and, as a `float`, is more than `FLT_MAX`.

```
// OP's
int IsInfinity(double d) {
  return d != (double)INFINITY && (float)d == INFINITY;
}
```

---

> if there's a way to check without triggering this warning.

Alternate:

Check via the max values:

```
int IsInfinity_alt(double d) {
  if (d < 0) d = -d;  // OP can not use fabs().
  return ((float)d > FLT_MAX && d <= DBL_MAX);
}
```

---

Had code used the below, some `double`, just bigger than `FLT_MAX` function differently than above.  It is possible that this behavior is preferred by OP.

```
return (d > FLT_MAX && d <= DBL_MAX);
```

Comment: I just want to say this is also an extremely good answer