# No compiler error on using garbage characters in #include statement

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c-preprocessor

```
#include <iostream> gfhgfhgf
using namespace std;

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Why does this code snippet compile? As per [The gcc reference on Include Syntax](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html):

> It is an error if there is anything (other than comments) on the line after the file name.

and that's exactly what's being done in the code.

Comment: What's your compiler? Mine (`clang-600.0.51`) issues a warning.

Comment: The MSVC2013 preprocessor grammar also explicitly disallows it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2scxys89.aspx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using the `-pedantic-errors` flags in `gcc` and `clang` turns this into an error [see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60aec0560894e4ce):

```
error: extra tokens at end of #include directive
#include <iostream> gfhgfhgf
                    ^
```

which indicates it is an extension.

If we look at the [Interfacing C and TAL In The Tandem Environment](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/tandem/TR-91.1.pdf) they have some code like this:

```
#include <stdlibh> nolist
                   ^^^^^^
```

So both `gcc` and `clang` support extra characters after the include directive to support an extension needed on some platforms. Using the [-pedantic flags](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html) makes `gcc` and `clang` produce a warning for extensions that violate the standard and as noted above you can use `-pendatic-errors` to turn this into an error (*emphasis mine*):

> to **obtain all the diagnostics required by the standard**, you should
>   also specify -pedantic (or -pedantic-errors if you want them to be
>   errors rather than warnings).

We can find a reference for the `nolist` extension in the [HP'sC/C++ Programmers guide for NonStop Systrms](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c02128447) which says:

> ```
> nolist
>   directs the compiler not to list the contents of the file or sections
>   being included.
> This is an HP NonStop  extension to the standard.
> ```

Note, the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) defines the grammar for this form of `include` in section `16.2` *[cpp.include]* as follows:

```
# include < h-char-sequence> new-line
```