# Trailing characters with #include directive

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c-preprocessor, code-formatting

I had a seemingly innocuous line in a source file

```
#include <some_sys_header_file.h>"
```

It was buried with a bunch of other includes that were using double-quotes (rather than angle brackets) so the spurious double-quote wasn't spotted.

The compiler (or rather, pre-processor) was happy, included the required file, and skipped the rest of the line.

But, when formatting the file using [Artistic Style](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/), the double-quote caused chaos with literal strings being incorrectly split over multiple lines.

Is there a standard for how this should be treated?

Comment: Can you give us the environment on which this source file was compiled/tired?

Comment: `gcc` is likely to issue one or two warnings in such cases.

Comment: @SantoshA: Embarcadero C++Builder 2010, which is a:old, b:wilfully non standards-compliant. But I'm more interested in what *should* happen according to the standard.

Comment: This may be [related to this extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27817081/1708801) since some systems use extra characters after the include.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is *undefined behavior*.

C99 says in 6.10 that an #include directive has the form

```
# include pp-tokens new-line
```

The only pp-tokens starting with a `"` are a string literal (C99 6.4.5 *String literals*) and a header-name in double quotes (C99 6.4.7 *Header names*). However, string literals must not contain un-escaped new-lines and header-names must not contain new-lines.
The lone `"` also cannot be part of a header-name since it is not within `<>` (C99 6.4.7 *Header names*).
What's left according to C99 6.4 *Lexical elements* is

> *preprocessing-token*:
>           ...
>           each non-white-space character that cannot be one of the above

In conjunction with the *Semantics* in paragraph 3

> If a `'` or a `"` character matches the last category, the behavior is
>   undefined.

So you might or might not get a diagnostic.

Answer (score 0):

When Standards were written, some compilers didn't use normal string-parsing logic on their `#include` arguments (especially the angle-bracket form which isn't used anywhere else).  Since the closing angle bracket isn't supposed to be followed by anything other than white space, it would be legitimate for a compiler to simply erase the last non-whitepsace character (which should be an angle bracket) without checking what it is, and use whatever precedes it as a file name.  This, a compiler could regard:

```
#include <stdio.h> Hey
```

as a request to include a file called `stdio.h> He`.  While that particular behavior might not be useful, it might hypothetically be necessary to use C in an environment that uses `>` as a path-separator character, and which might thus require:

```
#include <graphlib>drawing.h>
```

Since including characters after the intended header name could cause a compiler to `#include` a file other than the one intended, and since such a file could do anything whatsoever, include directives other than those defined by the standard are considered Undefined Behavior.  Personally, I think the language would benefit greatly if an additional form were standardized:

```
#include "literal1" "literal2" ["literal3", etc.]
```

with string concatenation applied in the usual fashion.  Many projects I've worked with have had absurdly long lists of include paths, the need for which could have been greatly mitigated if it were possible to say:

```
#include "fooproject_directories.h"
#include ACMEDIR "acme.h"
#include IOSYSDIR "io.h"
```

etc. thus making clear which files were supposed to be loaded from where.  Although it is possible that some code somewhere might rely upon the ability to say:

```
#include "this"file.h"
```

as a means of loading a file called `this"file.h` I think the Standard could accommodate such things by having such treatments be considered non-normative, requiring that any implementations document such non-normative behavior, and not requiring strictly-compliant programs to work on such non-normative platforms.